# Why do I suddenly have to place global:: in front of all my Razer @model models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, azure

I created an Azure solution with a WebRole project called MainWebRole and everything worked just fine. But now all of a sudden my view's won't accept binding a model to them using

```
@model MainWebRole.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

I have to place global:: infront, like this:

```
@model global::MainWebRole.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

I a baffled and I have no idea what caused this, and no idea how to fix it. I tried creating a new solution and everything works fine there. But I would like to know what caused this just in case something like this happens later.

Also there is a red squiggly-line under the word MainWebRole giving hint:

```
Module 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.2.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken...' should be referenced
```

But this is confirmed referenced in the MainWebRole project.

I am aware that more information might be needed to be published, but I am unsure of what to show.

I am using

```
Visual Studio 2013 Pro
Re-Sharper 8.2
Azure Storage Emulator 2.2.1
Azure Storage 3.0.3.0
```

Comment: I would guess that MainWebRole is your root namespace, but someone has created a type with that name.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks to your tip I found a line inside the web.config file residing in the Views folder. And I had an <add namespace="MainWebRole">, I guess I thought it belonged there so I never thought to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think this is a little bit off-topic since the `global` is not related with azure, but .net framework. Basically you need to use it if .net compiler cannot figure out which namespace you are referring so you need to add `global::` so that compiler will look for the namespace from the root of .net.

Here is a good article from MSDN told about it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx